# d3.js brushed area map to domain values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was following some simple values to create line chart with d3.js. Just come across some question about brushed area "mapping" to domain values.

```
      var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-100,100]).range([0, 500]), //domain and range for example

      var brush = d3.brushX()                   // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
          .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height2] ] )  // initialise the brush area
          .on("brush end", brushed);               // trigger the brushed function 

      function brushed() {
          var s = d3.event.selection; //get the selection pixel range on screen, [200,300] for example
          x.domain(s.map(x.invert, x)); // how does the s.map(x.invert,x) work
          //then update the chart with the new domain
      }
```

In `brushed`, s is two element array, represent the x_start and x_end of the screen selection.

`Console.log` shows `s.map(x.invert, x)`inverted range values in `s` to domain values.

How does `s.map(x.invert, x)` work?

Why not use `s.map(x.invert)` ? it seems to do the same thing. what is the purpose of `x` in the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right. This has nothing to do with `d3`, but with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Now, what the docs say about that is that it accepts *two* arguments, a function `callback`, and `thisArg`.

```js
let new_array = arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

`thisArg` is optional, but when given, `this` inside the callback, points to it. In this case, that means that `this === x`. I've checked the source and `d3` doesn't use `this` in any of their `.invert` functions, so you're safe either way.